# How to Implement Expect Response Body keyword of Robot Framework?

Tags: json, robotframework

**response body**

```
 "_embedded": {
        "Food": [
                "percent": 1.0000
        ]
    }
```

**For validation of  the Response body
I use like following on Robot file**

```
| | Expect Response Body |  ${list['response']}
```

**i am driving response  variable  through csv file which is same**

```
 embedded": {
        "Food": [
                "percent": 1.0000
        ]enter code here
    }
```

**But on running , getting following error**

```
Input is not valid JSON or a file:  "_embedded": {
        "Food": [
                "percent": 1.0000
        ]
    }
```

***What's wrong i am doing here?***

Comment: Even the first "json" is not a valid json. You can start there and figure out why it's not valid. You can check it quickly here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Aside from the JSON typo, can you add complete examples of your code. These snippets don't tell us which keywords form what libraries are used and thus how to interpret your observations.